# 403 Forbidden mistake for files in media using django and apache

Tags: python, django, apache

I use django with version 1.8 and apache server with version 2.4 on production to run my site.Besides I have  django-wysiwyg-redactor to upload images in RedactorField of my models. I use DEBUG = False on production.
I add such configurations in settings.py for my django project for media folder:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

And for redactor:

```
REDACTOR_UPLOAD = 'uploads/'
```

When I add permissions for folder media with such command:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 media/
```

And make configuration of apache 000-default.conf which has the such path /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf like:

```
Alias /static /home/ubuntu/webapps/simple_blog/assets
Alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/webapps/simple_blog/media

<Directory /home/ubuntu/webapps/simple_blog/assets>
     Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ubuntu/webapps/simple_blog/media>
     Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ubuntu/webapps/simple_blog/myblog>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

At now moment all urls and static works, except files in my media. When I upload images I connect by ssh to my server and I can find them in the /home/ubuntu/webapps/simple_blog/media/uploads. But while I upload file I can see in brauser console such mistake NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://example.com/media/uploads/a.jpeg". Where example.com is the name of my domain. And images dont view in the pages of site in console appeare the same mistake.
In the end I dont change any settings in apache except 000-default.conf.

Besides I find apache error.log file and find in that file such description of error:AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ubuntu/webapps/simple_blog/mediauploads

Comment: In additional I have  Ubuntu Server 14.04

Comment: At least i solve that problem the wrong allias for media: Alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/webapps/simple_blog/media/